# Как установить собственный автоинкремент в определённой таблице в базе данных SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Имею базу данных SQLite с двумя таблицами: days и months. В каждой из таблиц есть поле id с автоинкрементом.
Я хочу установить автоинкремент 9 в таблице months, но как это сделать?

В интернете я нашёл вот такой способ:

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 9
```

Но мне нужно установить автоинкремент в определённой таблице, а конкретно в таблице month, а этот способ как я понимаю устанавливает автоинкремент во всей бд